# Early '80s sci-fi/fantasy graphic novel made with real photographs?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember checking it out from the library when I was a kid. It is set on an alien planet; there is a woman in a diaphanous white gown who, at one point, rides on the back of a centaur-type creature (as a boy, I was quite taken with the fact that there is partial nudity in a few panels). The most striking thing about it was that the panel images were not drawn but were actual photographs.

Answer (score 9):

### ["Amberstar: An Illustrated Cosmic Odyssey"](https://web.archive.org/web/20170401134420/http://bronzeageofblogs.blogspot.com/2015/11/amberstar-illustrated-cosmic-odyssey.html) (1980) by Bruce Jones

The blog writer gives a brief overview of what sort of media this is.

> Just ticked this baby off the want list by finally scoring a copy, after years of seeing it advertised in the back of endless Warren mags. It's a sort of fotonovel / fumetti by Bruce Jones, one of comics' consistently great writers, with what seems to be an uncredited assist from Richard Corben, or in fact some of his assistants.
> Like a lot of Byron Preiss' output, Amberstar isn't quite a comic book, nor quite a graphic novel, but one of those fascinating near misses the Bronze Age was full of, and which I'm a total sucker for.
> Each 'panel' consists of a black & white photo, overlayed in colour at Corben's studio, in a similiar way to his Doomscult strip, seen in Heavy Metal ( and on this blog! ), which also starred one Bruce Jones.
> Amberstar isn't wholly successful, looking in places like a colourized movie, and some of the spacescapes cry out for Corben's specific hand in the colouring, but these are minor quibbles really, and this is a space opera like no other.

***It is set on an alien planet; there is a woman in a diaphanous white gown who, at one point, rides on the back of a centaur-type creature***

[image: Amberstar: An Illustrated Cosmic Odyssey woman on Centaur]

***as a boy, I was quite taken with the fact that there is partial nudity in a few panels***

It isn't really explicit but NSFW warning anyway as it is a "nude" scene.

> [image: Amberstar: An Illustrated Cosmic Odyssey nudity scene]

Comment: Hi there! This is a *great* find! But since links tend to rot, could you maybe [edit] in some more info from that website? :)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you're talking about Frank Franzetta's art and in particular Epic Illustrated.
Is this the one with the woman riding on the centaur?

**Warning (NSFW - Nudity)!**

> [image]

I was in a discussion with friends where the topic had come up (for the first time in decades it seems, I hadn't thought about it since the mid 90s). Among other things I came across your thread while looking for examples online. Hope it is what you're looking for!

Comment: The OP states that "the panel images were not drawn but were actual photographs". I don't think Frazetta's work matches that description, though I have no idea whose does.